# ElasticSearch, row ACL

Tags: elasticsearch, proxy, kibana

**Background:**
I've started dumping several hunderds of GBs to Elastic Search in an attempt to make my query faster through denormalization. They are faster indeed!

At this point I would like to expose `one index` directly to our internal users (complex schema with hundreds of fields and complex queries we cannot get around) with just one little restrictions, row level ACL:

**Problem**

given an index defined as

```
PUT my_denormalized_index/_mapping
{
   "properties": {
     "allowedUsers": [ARRAY OF SOME SORT],
     "all_the_rest_of_secret_data": { 
       "type": "nested"
     }
   }
}
```

I want that my users are able to query only the data in which their ID is within "allowedUsers".

**Options I'm considering**

Is there a `Standard` way to do this? Like giving a user access only to one index and enforcing adding a WHERE condition in all queries?

Either through ElasticSearch configuration, or some kind of standard proxy that enriches the query?

Other options evaluated

- giving straight access to Kibana --> I'm new to ES, but my understanding is that they would have full access
- giving them access to a proxy that every time they create a query will also add `match{allowedUsers: contains myId1}`

Hence, since I believe that ES search is not Newby-friendly, I would like to give the same autocomplete experience you would have in Kibana, but using this kind of proxy.

Any advice?

Comment: Please remove [kql] tag - which is used for Kusto Query Language

Answer (score 0):

If you have a platinum licence or more and a recent version of elastic search, it's quite easy to do.

You can create a role with some RBAC based on a meta data of your user. But each user of your application need to  have their own credentials.

If not, you should enforce a filter parameter at your proxy/application side.
You can think of forcing usage a some search template to keep more control on end users actions.

If you want to have this behavior in Kibana, I think their is no other possibility than use the RBAC of the platinium licence.